# How to create pdf receipt file in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, reportlab

I am making an online store using google app engine (python).
I need to create a simple pdf receipt and send to customer.

Please recommend me the most simple method.
I have tried reportlab, but I got problem in import reportlab:

```
  2015-02-17 20:36:43.152
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.382295241559540129/kay/app.py", line 361, in get_response
    view_func = import_string(view_func)

  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.382295241559540129/kay/lib/werkzeug/utils.py", line 422, in import_string
    __import__(modname)

  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.382295241559540129/myapp/views.py", line 48, in <module>
    from reportlab.lib import colors

  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.382295241559540129/myapp/reportlab/lib/colors.py", line 43, in <module>
    from reportlab import isPy3

ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'myapp.views.order1'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'myapp' found in '/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.382295241559540129/myapp/__init__.pyc'.
- 'myapp.views' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named reportlab
W 2015-02-17 20:36:43.153
500: import_string() failed for 'myapp.views.order1'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'myapp' found in '/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.382295241559540129/myapp/__init__.pyc'.
- 'myapp.views' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named reportlab
I 2015-02-17 20:36:43.157
Saved; key: __appstats__:003000, part: 24 bytes, full: 1598 bytes, overhead: 0.000 + 0.003; link: http://xxx.appspot.com/_ah/stats/details?time=1424173003069
```

Answer (score 2):

We use pisa from xhtml2pdf package.

Use `pip install xhtml2pdf -t .` to install it into your project directory (it should install all dependencies as well, but you should check).

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
output = StringIO()  # we cannot use filesystem on gae, so write it in the memory
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF('<strong>Hello, world!</strong>', output, encoding='utf-8')
pdf_data = pdf.dest.getvalue()
print pdf_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Reportlab is fine, what seems to be your problem is that the package should be in your root directory, alongside `app.yaml`, that will take care of the import errors.

You can get the source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab), remember to only copy the directory named `reportlab` under `src`.

[Here's a simple tutorial](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Generating-PDFs-on-App-Engine-Python-and-introducing-Mapvelopes), the first example should work without any problems if the "installation" was done properly.